# Clustering methods that do not require pre-specifying the number of clusters

Tags: clustering

Are there any "non-parametric" clustering methods for which we don't need to specify the number of clusters? And other parameters like the number of points per cluster, etc.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Clustering algorithms that require you to pre-specify the number of clusters are a small minority.  There are a huge number of algorithms that don't.  They are hard to summarize; it's a bit like asking for a description of any organisms that aren't cats.

Clustering algorithms are often categorized into broad kingdoms:

1. Partitioning algorithms (like [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and it's progeny)
2. Hierarchical clustering (as [@Tim describes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/241387/7290))
3. Density based clustering (such as [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN))
4. Model based clustering (e.g., [finite Gaussian mixture models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model), or [Latent Class Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_class_model))

There can be additional categories, and people can disagree with these categories and which algorithms go in which category, because this is heuristic.  Nevertheless, something like this scheme is common.  Working from this, it is primarily only the partitioning methods (1) that require pre-specification of the number of clusters to find.  What other information needs to be pre-specified (e.g., the number of points per cluster), and whether it seems reasonable to call various algorithms 'nonparametric', is likewise highly variable and hard to summarize.

Hierarchical clustering does not require you to *pre-specify* the number of clusters, the way that k-means does, but you do select a number of clusters from your output. On the other hand, DBSCAN doesn't require either (but it does require specification of a minimum number of points for a 'neighborhood'—although there are defaults, so in some sense you could skip specifying that—which does put a floor on the number of patterns in a cluster). GMM doesn't even require any of those three, but does require parametric assumptions about the data generating process.  As far as I know, there is no clustering algorithm that never requires you to specify a number of clusters, a minimum number of data per cluster, or any pattern / arrangement of data within clusters.  I don't see how there could be.

It might help you to read an overview of different types of clustering algorithms.  The following might be a place to start:

- Berkhin, P. "Survey of Clustering Data Mining Techniques" ([pdf](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~isbell/reading/papers/berkhin02survey.pdf))

Comment: I am confused by your #4: I thought if one fits a Gaussian mixture model to the data then one needs to choose the number of Gaussians to fit, i.e. the number of clusters has to be specified in advance. If so, why do you say that "primarily only" #1 requires this?

Comment: @amoeba, it depends on the model based method & how it's implemented. GMMs are often fit to minimize some criterion (as, eg, OLS regression is, cf [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/114664/7290)). If so, you do not pre-specify the number of clusters. Even if you do according to some other implementation, it isn't a typical feature for model based methods.

Comment: What you did in the linked answer (or perhaps what the corresponding R function did for you) is probably to fit GMMs with 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. clusters, to compare the resulting BICs, and to choose the "optimal" one, yielding $k=3$. I would still describe it as pre-specifying the number of clusters and using some additional *general* heuristic to choose the best fitting model, but I can see that an argument can be made in favour of saying that, overall, $k$ does not need to be pre-specified. However, can't one use BIC with k-means too? If so, then k-means and GMM appear to be in the same boat.

Comment: I don't really follow your argument here, @amoeba. When you fit a simple regression model w/ the OLS algorithm, would you say that you are pre-specifying the slope & intercept, or that the algorithm specifies them by optimizing a criterion? If the latter, I don't see what's different here. It is certainly true that you could create a new meta-algorithm that uses k-means as one of its steps to find a partition w/o pre-specifying k, but that meta-algorithm would not be k-means.

Comment: Regression coefficients are not pre-specified, no question about that. The criterion that is optimized in regression is sum of squared errors. In GMM I would think that the criterion is the likelihood of all points, and to optimize this criterion one *does* need to pre-specify $k$. Hence my confusion. If you mean that the criterion is BIC, then I would say that this already becomes a "meta-algorithm" (GMM + model selection), but this I guess is more of a terminological issue.

Comment: @amoeba, this does seem to be a semantic issue, but the standard algorithms used to fit a GMM typically optimize a criterion. Eg, the one `Mclust` uses is designed to optimize the BIC, but the AIC could be used or a sequence of likelihood ratio tests. I guess you could call it a meta-algorithm, b/c it has constituent steps (eg, EM), but that is the algorithm you use, & at any rate it does not require you to pre-specify k. You can clearly see in my linked example that I did not pre-specify k there.

Comment: The GMM *model* is different from the GMM clustering algorithm that fits it, just as a regression model is different from the OLS estimation procedure. The 'model' that results from k-means is just a partition of the data, the algorithm that finds that partition is called k-means & that algorithm requires you to specify k in advance. You could create a different algorithm to find a partition, but it wouldn't be k-means.

Comment: I would segment clustering methods, with respect to k, into 1) those where k is selected at the beginning; 2) those where k is selected in the end, i.e. after assignment of points to clusters is fulfilled; 3) those where k is selected halfway. By enveloping a clustering method together with a criterion to prefer k into a higher-order single algorithm one moves from type to type. For example, repeated k-means+criterion turns it from (1) into (3).

Comment: No problem, @amoeba, sorry I wasn't clear from the beginning. I'm wondering if we should clean up this comment thread. Do you think there are some points here that should be moved into the answer?

Comment: NO NO NO. Refer to your discussion part "As far as I know, there is no clustering algorithm that never requires you to specify a number of clusters, a minimum number of data per cluster, or any pattern / arrangement of data within clusters. I don't see how there could be.", there is indeed a method that does not require you to specify number of clusters and it's state of the art method that was published in a VERY HIGH QUALITY Journal "Science", "https://science.sciencemag.org/content/315/5814/972". DONOT UNDERESTIMATE HUMAN BEINGS, some guys are  amazing .

Answer (score 14):

The most simple example is [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering), where you compare each point with each other point using some [distance measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance), and then join together the pair that has the smallest distance to create joined pseudo-point (e.g. *b* and *c* makes *bc* as on the image below). Next you repeat the procedure by joining the points, and pseudo-points, based their pairwise distances until each point is joined with the graph.

[image: Wikipedia illustration]

(source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering)

The procedure is non-parametric and the only thing that you need for it is the distance measure. In the end you need to decide how to *prune* the tree-graph created using this procedure, so a decision about expected number of clusters needs to be made.

Comment: Isn't pruning somehow means that you are deciding on cluster number?

Comment: @MedNait that is what I said. In cluster analysis you *always* have to make such decision, the only question is *how* is it made -- e.g. it could be arbitrary, or it could be based on some reasonable criterion like likelihood-based model fit etc.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you are after, @MedNait. Hierarchical clustering does not require you to *pre-specify* the number of clusters, the way that k-means does, but you are selecting a number of clusters from your output. On the other hand, DBSCAN doesn't require either (but it does require specification of a minimum number of points for a 'neighborhood'--although there are defaults--which does put a floor on the number of patterns in a cluster). GMM doesn't even require that, but does require parametric assumptions about the data generating process. Etc.

Answer (score 12):

## Parameters are good!

A "parameter-free" method means that you only get a single shot (except for maybe randomness), with no **customization** possibilities.

Now clustering is a *explorative* technique. **You must not assume there is a single "true" clustering**. You should rather be interested in *exploring* different clusterings of the same data to learn more about it. Treating clustering as a black box never works well.

For example, you want to be able to customize the *distance function* used depending on your data (this is also a parameter!) If the result is too coarse, you want to be able to get a finer result, or if it is too fine, get a coarser version of it.

The best methods often are those that let you navigate the result well, such as the dendrogram in hierarchical clustering. You can then explore substructures easily.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Dirichlet mixture models](https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~jcorso/t/2009S_555/files/lecture7.dirichlet.pdf).  They're provide a good way of making sense of the data if you don't know the number of clusters beforehand.  However, they do make assumptions about the shapes of clusters, which your data might violate.

Comment: Dirichlet processes (and their generalization Pitman-Yor processes) are reasonable approaches to clustering that don't require specifying the number of clusters in advance. However, keep in mind that Dirichlet and Pitman-Yor processes are not consistent estimators of the number of clusters: https://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/miller14a/miller14a.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the number of clusters only from the input data, for numerical variables you may look at MCG, a hierarchical clustering method with an automatic stop criterion: see the free seminar paper at https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02124947/document (contains bibliographic references); the input data is either the array of coordinates of the N data points, or an N by N array of distances between the N items (the distances are not required to be Euclidean ones).

If you are working on categorical variables, you may look at POP (optimal partitioning); the method is presented in the same seminar paper; it operates either on categorical variables or on an N by N array of signed dissimilarities (the main cited paper was published in 2002: free copy at https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02123085/document).

There are [free binaries](http://petitjeanmichel.free.fr/itoweb.petitjean.freeware.html) for MCG and POP (at least for linux). Indeed the two methods are explained (with examples) in English in the seminar paper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would help if you described the methods a bit further, because the first document you linked is just a presentation and the second is in French.