# Determine clusters for the encodings of a Siamese Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, clustering, conv-neural-network

I implemented a Siamese Neural Network that encodes images of different objects and outputs "coordinates" for each image in a lower dimension. My goal is to measure how good the network is clustering the images.

If I visualize the coordinates in two to three dimensions (by applying PCA) I can clearly see that images of the same object are close to each other. The algorithm works well enough. Therefore, I am defining the clusters based on the ground truth labels, which is obviously not the best approach.

So my question is how should I determine the real clusters and also what would be the best measure to determine how "good" those clusters are?

I thought about running a clustering algorithm (such as k-Means) on top of the encoding and then use an external validation metric such as the F-Score to measure the goodness of the overall model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches; direct methods and statistical testing methods:

Direct methods: consists of optimizing a criterion, such as the within-cluster sums of squares or the average silhouette. The corresponding methods are named elbow and silhouette methods, respectively.

Statistical testing methods: consists of comparing evidence against the null hypothesis. An example is the gap statistic.

1. Elbow method - see this paper for details. Essentially, a line is plotted on a graph and the **bend** in the line indicates a possible number of clusters. In R it can be done using the `NBClust` package.
2. Average silhouette method computes the average silhouette of observations for different values of k. The optimal number of clusters k is the one that maximizes the average silhouette over a range of possible values for k (Kaufman and Rousseeuw 1990).
3. The gap statistic compares the total within intra-cluster variation for different values of k with their expected values under the null reference distribution of the data. The estimate of the optimal clusters will be a value that maximizes the gap statistic (i.e, that yields the largest gap statistic). This means that the clustering structure is far away from the random uniform distribution of points.

The `fviz_nbclust()` function `[in factoextra R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/factoextra/index.html) can be used to compute the three different methods elbow, silhouette and gap statistic for any partitioning clustering methods like K-means, K-medoids (PAM), CLARA, HCUT.

Besides, you can also look at some similar questions asked in [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23472/how-to-decide-on-the-correct-number-of-clusters), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241381/clustering-methods-that-do-not-require-pre-specifying-the-number-of-clusters)

For cluster validation metrics, see this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79028/performance-metrics-to-evaluate-unsupervised-learning)

Finally, remember clustering is an explorative technique. Assuming "true" clusters is a paradox. Your objective should be in exploring different clusterings of the same data to learn more about it. Treating clustering as a black box never works well.