# Initialization of Kmeans++ clusters

Tags: clustering, k-means

I would like to confirm the initialization steps of my K-means++ implementation (steps which chose initial centers of clusters). I am wondering if my initialization scheme has been implemented correctly. Here is my pseudocode:

```
   select one data item at random as the first mean
   loop k-1 times
        compute distance from each item to closest mean
        select an item that has large distance-squared as next initial mean
   end loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-Mean++ is an algorithm for choosing the initial values (or "seeds") for the k-means clustering algorithm. It was proposed in 2007 by [David Arthur and Sergei Vassilvitskii](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf), as an approximation algorithm for the NP-hard k-means problem—a way of avoiding the sometimes poor clusterings found by the standard k-means algorithm.

The exact algorithm is as follows:

1. Choose one center uniformly at random from among the data points.
2. For each data point x, compute D(x), the distance between x and the nearest center that has already been chosen.
3. Choose one new data point at random as a new center, using a weighted probability distribution where a point x is chosen with probability proportional to D(x)2.
4. Repeat Steps 2 and 3 until k centers have been chosen.
5. Now that the initial centers have been chosen, proceed using standard k-means clustering.

Besides this, you may find the following answers helpful too; [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466323/how-exactly-does-k-means-work), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317493/methods-of-initializing-k-means-clustering), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405967/determine-clusters-for-the-encodings-of-a-siamese-neural-network) and [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793532/how-do-i-determine-k-when-using-k-means-clustering?rq=1)

Reference: http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf

Answer (score 0):

K-means++ does not select the element with the largest distance.

It uses a *weighted random* to prefer farther elements.